# checking returned children in knockout js

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, knockout.js

i am using knockout to display items on page. I have a list of groups ex: Group 1, Group 2,... each group is in it's own div. When i click on one of the groups it will open and display the items in the group. Some of my groups don't have any items to display and instead of it not showing anything i would like to change that to display: "No items in group"

I am having trouble doing this in the view in javascript and thought i would be able to do it in my knockout/jquery script

View:

```
<div class="accordion-group elements-by-item">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="ui_title accordion-toggle text_x-large item_accordion_toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ByTimeIndex"
                data-bind="text: Title() != null ? Title() : Identity(), attr: { 'href': '#itemContent_' + Id(), 'data-item-id': Id() }">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse state-loading" data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'itemContent_' + Id(), 'data-item-id': Id() }">
            @Html.Partial("_itemElements")
        </div>
    </div>


    **_itemElements Page:**

    <div class="accordion-inner no_border" data-bind="foreach: Children">
                        <div class="element">
                        ........
                        </div>
    <div>
```

**knockout/Jquery js**

```
$idx.ItemsRetrieved = new Array();

    $idx.GetItemContent = function (element) {
        var _itemId = element.attr('data-item-id');
        var _elementData = $idx.itemData;

        this.GetElementContent({
            groupId: _itemId,
            groupData: _elementData.items,
            elementData: _elementData,
            apiUrl: _courseIndexOptions.GetitemUrlPrefix + _itemId,
            accordionBodySelector: '.accordion-body[data-item-id="' + _itemId + '"]',
            accordionBtnSelector: 'a[data-item-id="' + _itemId + '"]',
            viewModel: $idx.TimeViewModel
        });
    }

    $idx.GetElementContent = function (options) {
        if (linq.From($idx.ItemsRetrieved).Any(function (x) { return x == options.groupId })) {
            $(options.accordionBodySelector).removeClass(constants.StateClasses.Loading);           
            return;                                                                                 
        }

        return Ajax.Get({
            Url: options.apiUrl,
            OnSuccess: function (data) {
                var _items = linq.From(options.groupData);                                          
                var _itemToUpdate = _items.Where(function (x) { return x.Id == options.groupId; });
                if (_itemToUpdate.Any()) {
                    _itemToUpdate.First().Children = data.Items;                                
                }

                ko.mapping.fromJS(options.elementData, options.viewModel);                         
                sections.ElementArray.AddRange(data.Items);                                     

                $(options.accordionBodySelector).removeClass(constants.StateClasses.Loading);       
                $idx.ItemsRetrieved.push(options.groupId);                                       
                $(options.accordionBtnSelector).click();                                           
            }
        });
```

how can i check if the children ItemsRetrieved = 0 and to set a message "No Items" to show in the view page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that :

```
<div class="accordion-inner no_border" >
    <div data-bind="foreach: Children">
        <div class="element">
        </div>
    </div>
    <span data-bind="if : Children().length == 0">No items in group</span>
<div>
```

I hope it helps.